# Extracting HTML Link from Javascript Associative Array to apply to D3 Generated Table

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

**Problem:** The HTML link that I'm extracting from an Associative Array does not get applied as a link but, rather, as a string, so the HTML Link is not traversable by the browser.

**Full Visual Example and Code:** located at: http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/6366020

**Data:** I have a Javascript Array of Associative Arrays.

```
  var densitySet = [
    { Name: "<a href=\"http:if4it.com\">IF4IT</a>", Total: 1000 },
    { Name: "Node2", Total: 1500 },
    .
    .
    .
    { Name: "Node3", Total: 700 },
    { Name: "Node27", Total: 1500 }
  ];
```

You'll notice that the first element of the first Associative Array has a data element that is an HTML link.  I want to extract that link and apply it to a cell of an HTML table that I'm generating using D3.

**Symptom:** When the table renders, the full HTML path is rendered as a string and not as a traversable HTML link.

The code that extracts the link data and applies it to the cell is as follows...

```
     var densityBodyDataRecords = d3.selectAll("#density_body_record").selectAll("tr.td")
      .data(function(d) { return densityKeys.map(function(k) { return d[k]; }); })
      .enter()
        .append("td")
          .attr("id", "density_body_data")
          //.text(function(d) { return d; })
          .text(function(d, i) {
            if(i < 2) { return d; } <------------------TEXT APPLIED HERE
          })
          .style("font-size", "10pt")
          .append("svg")
            .attr("width", function(d, i) {
              if(i == 0) { return 200; }
              else if(i == 1) { return 100; }
              else { return 500; }
            })
            //.attr("height", 15)
            .attr("height", function(d, i) {
              if(i < 2) { return 0; }
              else { return 15; }
            })
            .append("rect")
              .attr("height", 15)
              .style("fill", "Blue")
              .attr("width", function(d, i) {
                if(i == 2) { return (d/maxRelationshipValue)*100*5; }
        else { return 0; }
              });
```

Any ideas on how to fix this are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays. They're just called "objects".

Comment: Oh, also, giving lots of elements the same "id" value is going to cause problems. The "id" of each element must be unique within the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your content to be parsed as HTML, you have to call `.html()`, not `.text()`.

Comment: Hi Pointy, I believe the issue is that the other data elements in the associative array are not HTML.  In this case, the next element is a number and, in extended versions, there can even be more elements with more numbers, text, and/or HTML.  Is there a way to alternate or switch between the ".text()" in cases for strings or numbers and ".html()" in cases for html? -- Thx.

Comment: You have to make that decision yourself. You'll have to include something in the data to tell your code whether the content to be added is HTML markup or not. Then your code can decide which API to call.  There's no jQuery API that just "figures it out" for you.

Comment: I'm ok with that if I can find the syntax to switch between the two.  The problem seems to be in that the javascript chaining requires .append().text() or .append().html() for all data.  I don't know how to do conditional chaining so I could toggle between the two.  Do you?

Comment: @InformationTechnology actually I don't trust myself to give an explicit code example because I barely know d3.  Basically, you can use `.each` I think to provide a place where you can make the decision.

Comment: I tested it and using the .html() function is what works.  For some reason, it handles numbers/numerics and plain string with no issues and only translates HTML strings to linkable addresses.  So your original answer works.